# Typescript typing a wrapping function that assumes the type of the function wrapped

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

**Overview and purpose:** 
I am attempting to write a function that is a wrapper for functions passed in as an argument; where the function in question assumes the typing of the function passed in as an argument.

It would seem that this is a common use case in typescript however after searching it would seem that none of the posted solutions seemed to cover my use case.

**Here is an example situation**:

```js
export interface LockParams {
  id: string;
}

export interface LockRecord {
  id: string;
  createdOn: string;
}

export async function acquireLock(params: LockParams): Promise<LockRecord> {
  // talk to database and return a value of LockRecord
}

export async function deleteLock(params: LockParams): Promise<void> {
  // talk to database and delete a lock record.
}

export interface DoWorkParams {
  id: string;
  customerName: string;
}

export interface DoWorkResponse {
  id: string;
  customerName: string;
  createdOn: string;
}

export async function doWork(params: DoWorkParams): Promise<DoWorkResponse> {
  // do work implementation 
}
```

My Question:
How can I define a function that allows `doWork` with params to be sent to it? In this case I desire to have said function acquire a lock, preform the `doWork` function, then delete the lock upon completion, then return the response from `doWork`; all while having the wrapped function assume the input and response types from the `doWork` function.

Comment: do you want to send `doWork` with params into `acquireLock` ?

Comment: Can you add an example about how you want this new function to be called, maybe `let response: DoWorkResponse = await wrapper(doWork, doWorkParams)`?

Comment: Does you mean you have multiple different functions to `doWork`, and you want to use all of them with the "wrapper"? Where does the `LockParams` from for acquire a lock? Does all `DoWorkParams` has an `id` field for this?

Comment: Is it required that that wrapper only every accepts `doWork` or any function?

Comment: @Yoshi looking for any function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to change your requirements slightly, I think the following allows for very simple typing and gives greater flexibility:

```
async function withLock1<T>(
  lockParams: LockParams,
  fn: () => T | Promise<T>
): Promise<T> {
  await acquireLock(lockParams);
  const r = await fn();
  await deleteLock(lockParams);
  return r;
}

// call
const responseA: DoWorkResponse = await withLock1(
  {id: 'foo'}, 
  () => doWork({id: 'bar', customerName: 'name'})
);
```

---

Though if you really want to pass in the actual worker function aside it's parameters, this will work, and even error for unknown properties on the function parameters:

```
async function withLock2<T extends (...args: any) => any>(
  lockParams: LockParams,
  fn: T,
  ...params: Parameters<T>
): Promise<ReturnType<T>> {
  await acquireLock(lockParams);
  const r = await fn.call(params);
  await deleteLock(lockParams);
  return r;
}

// call
const responseB: DoWorkResponse = await withLock2(
  {id: 'foo'}, 
  doWork, 
  {id: 'bar', customerName: 'name'}
);
```

Both versions allow workers with multiple parameters as a bonus.

---

*Note*: Obviously you can change the implementation (as per your own answer). The one I chose is just for testing purposes.

The only thing I had to compromise on was:

```
fn.call(params);
```

instead of:

```
fn(...params);
```

because of an error someone else might shed a light on.

```
// TS2488: Type 'Parameters ' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to define a higher order function you can pass `doWork` to to execute it with locking. This could be done like this:

```
export async function doWorkWithLock(doWorkWorker: (params: DoWorkParams) => Promise<DoWorkResponse>, params: DoWorkParams): Promise<DoWorkResponse> {
  const lockParams = {id: params.id};

  const lockRecord = await acquireLock(lockParams);
  const workResponse = await doWorkWorker(params);
  await deleteLock(lockParams);

  return workResponse;
}
```

Which you can the run like this:

```
doWorkWithLock(doWork, doWorkParams);
```

The important part here you were probably wondering about is the type of the `doWorkWorker` parameter which has to be of the same type as the `doWork` function, i.e.

```
(params: DoWorkParams) => Promise<DoWorkResponse>
```

For more readability you could also define a type alias for this:

```
type DoWorkWorker = (params: DoWorkParams) => Promise<DoWorkResponse>;

export async function doWorkWithLock(doWorkWorker: DoWorkWorker, params: DoWorkParams): Promise<DoWorkResponse> {
  // ...
}

doWorkWithLock(doWork, doWorkParams);
```

If you - as per your comment - need a new function with the same type as `doWork` you need a wrapping function that again returns a (wrapped) function:

```
export function wrapWithLock(doWorkWorker: DoWorkWorker): DoWorkWorker {
  return async function wrappedWorker(params: DoWorkParams): Promise<DoWorkResponse> {
      const lockParams = {id: params.id};

      const lockRecord = await acquireLock(lockParams);
      const workResponse = await doWorkWorker(params);
      await deleteLock(lockParams);

      return workResponse;
  }
}

const doWorkWrapped = wrapWithLock(doWork);
```

`doWorkWrapped` has the same type as `doWork`, i.e. can be called interchangeably, will internally call `doWork` and return its result, but with locking.

Comment: Sorry, that is not exactly what I am looking for. What is in the title of the question is "wrapping function that assumes the type of the function wrapped".

Meaning if the function passed is doWork or any other type of function the wrapper should then assume the typing of the params as well as response regardless of what the type declaration is.

Comment: can you add an example of how you intent to call that function, what you would pass in and what the expected result would be?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I ended up coming up with.

```
export async function doWorkWithLock<P, R>(
  doWorkParams: P,
  lockParams: LockParams,
  doWork: (i: P) => Promise<R>
): Promise<R> {
  await acquireLock(lockParams); // will throw error if unable to acquire lock

  try {
    return await doWork(doWorkParams);
  } catch (error) {
    // TODO: log error

    throw error;
  } finally {
    await deleteLock(lockParams);
  }
}
```

So now I can use this function and do the following:

```
const lockParams: LockParams = {
    id: "example id",
}

const doWorkParams: DoWorkParams = {
  id: "do work id",
  customerName: "example name,
}

doWorkWithLock(doWorkParams, lockParams, doWork)
```

the `doWorkWithLock` function will now assume the typing of the `doWork` function (or any function passed in for that matter).

Comment: You solution allows for extra properties in `doWorkParams`. This might or might not be a problem.